# PHP Undefined index file upload

Tags: php

I have file input in php

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="fileup">
</form>
```

the error was "Undefine Index". here is my code for php.

```
<?php
$file = strtolower($_FILES["uploadpic"]["name"]);
?>
```

the undefined index was uploadpic.

Comment: Yeah - your input name is "fileup" not "uploadpic"

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your element is named `fileup` and you're using `["uploadpic"]`

- Both of those **must** match.

Either you do `$file = strtolower($_FILES["fileup"]["name"]);`

or rename your element to:

```
<input type="file" name="uploadpic">
```

- *The choice is yours.*

---

Reference links:

- http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: hahaha. thanks! but I already solved it by my own. that was my mistake. but thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score 0):

when calling or retrieving the post file data the name should be same as the name given in the file input field i.e. if your input name is `fileup` then you should retrieve data by `$_FILES['fileup']` instead of using `$_FILE[uploadpic]`